# Using state for logic during same render cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to implement a loader that display a number of posts using React with functional components. I am finding it hard to use the current state, changed in the current render cycle, to affect other logic in the component.

For example, in the code below, the intent is that when **query** changes, **getPosts()** is called and the posts are reloaded. Note that previously **endReached** is true, however **clearPosts()** should reset that and allow the load to go through. However, the console shows otherwise:

clearing posts

aborting get

Using class components, it is possible to have a callback when you change the state, such that you can be certain that the state has taken effect. How do you go about something like this in functional React?

Thanks.

```
const BrowsePosts = (props) => {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [endReached, setEndReached] = useState(false);
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

// refresh posts when query changes
useEffect(() => {
    clearPosts();
    getPosts();
}, [query]);

const clearPosts = () => {
    console.log("clearing posts");
    setPosts([]);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setEndReached(false);
}

const getPosts = async () => {
    if (isLoading || endReached) {
        console.log("aborting get");
        return;
    }

    console.log("getting posts");
    ...
    ...
}

...
...
```

Comment: seeing as the getPosts method run only when loading & endreach are false, why not just run it at every update  in a `useEffect(getPosts(),[])`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR The updates to state are only reflected in the next render of functional component. You can wait for your component to re-render, and use another `useEffect` to call `getPosts` in that cycle or if the use-case is simple enough, just remove the condition and rest of the code will work just fine.

Functional components are Functions first. All the normal rules of functions do apply to functional components. For example, the value of a constant `endReached` cannot change!

The way state works with React's functional components, is that when you call the `useState` the initial or last updated value is returned along with an update function. When you call the update function, react internally stores that new updated value of the corresponding state variable. Along with that it also flags the component to be re-rendered at a later point.

When react gets to re-rendering your component, it will call your Functional component as a function providing the props as parameter. This time when the `useState` call is made again, the latest updated value of the state variable will be returned. Incidentally, a new copy of all the functions declared within the component (`clearPosts`, `getPosts`, `unamed callback to useEffect` in your example) will also be created. These 'new' functions are the one which will see the 'latest' value of the state variable. All the functions created in old render cycles will forever continue to see the old value (if they somehow get called).

Ideally, if nothing too funky is done in the component, the callbacks, event handlers, etc should get updated with the new copies of the functions created within Component after every render and things should work fine. However, every once in a while one hits a scenario like above which reminds you yet again that, Functional components are just functions.

PS: If you need the changes to be reflected immediately, take a look at [`useRef` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#useref). Changes to refs will reflect immediately. However, it doesn't cause the component to re-render, so it isn't necessarily an replacement for `useState`. Depending on your use-case it might work though.